# Change console font in arch linux to ttf

Tags: linux, arch-linux, terminal, fonts, ttf

I have a .ttf font file which I want to use in my arch linux terminal. I followed the instructions for installing fonts on the wiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fonts#Changing_the_default_font

These are the steps I tried:

```
[root#archserver ~]# cp my_font.ttf /usr/share/kbd/consolefonts/
[root#archserver ~]# setfont my_font.ttf
Bad input file size
```

I am new to Arch so I'm probably missing something, do I need to convert from .ttf to .psf.gz?